# auto getter and setter in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript, getter-setter

I've created [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274789/javascript-beyond-property-accessors) (sort of auto getter and setter) for javaScript but I don't know how to implement this in typeScript

I want to make an Object Oriented version of that if that's possible.

Comment: Check out [using decorators](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/blob/big-picture/interop/reusability.md) to do something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there is no good way to do this. I think you will just need to go the boilerplate-y way:

```
class Foo {
    private _bar: number;
    get bar() { return this._bar }
    set bar(bar: number) { this._bar = bar}
    // ...
}
```

If you wanted, you could use an editor snippet to make this a bit less of a pain.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But I want auto getter and setter.

Answer (score 6):

7 years later, TypeScript 4.9 now supports an upcoming ECMAScript feature called "auto accessors":

```
class MyClass {
  // This property 
  accessor myProperty: boolean = true
}
```

This does not provide access to the underlying private property, though. You can read up on how these work and why these were introduced [here](https://2ality.com/2022/10/javascript-decorators.html#why-are-auto-accessors-needed%3F).